# The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Tags: eclipse, jsp

This is what I got on the browser screen when I try to run the JSP file.

> The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:

> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
>           org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
>           org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
>           org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)

And the jasper exception is thrown on the Tomcat window when I ran it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

That [method](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory.html#getJspApplicationContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29) was introduced in JSP 2.1. There are 3 causes for this problem:

1. You're using an too old version of the JSP container (you need for example at least [Tomcat 6.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)).
2. You've declared the wrong Servlet version in `web.xml`. JSP 2.1 goes hand in hand with Servlet 2.5, so your `web.xml` should at least be declared as per the Servlet 2.5 spec (you still need a Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1 capable servletcontainer for that).
3. You've duplicated older versioned appserver-specific libraries into webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, like `servlet-api.jar`, `jsp-api.jar` and so on. You should **never** do that. It will only result in classloading collisions. Get rid of them in your webproject and leave/untouch them there in the appserver.

Comment: ingcarlos,How did you resolve your issue? Which method did you use?

Comment: @janwen: just check any one of the listed causes.

Comment: Thanks BalusC,Cause1 and cause2 is ok.I delete servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar in my project.but still [code]An error occurred at line: 22 in the generated java file
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory[/code]

Comment: @janwen: then they're still wandering elsewhere in the classpath where they don't belong. For example, the `/lib` or `/lib/ext` folder of the JRE. Or you've other JARs containing an outdated JSP API, such as `javaee.jar`. After all, your `/WEB-INF/lib` should absolutely not contain any other libraries than the ones required by the webapp itself. See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: No,I see the WEB-INF/lib folders of tomcat6,There is no that jars.

Comment: @janwen: Tomcat6 != JRE. You should remove **any** servlet-container specific JARs which you've ever loosely downloaded/copied/moved anywhere in your entire environment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10524/discussion-between-janwen-and-balusc)

Answer (score 4):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>${servlet.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

also fixes the issues

Answer (score 1):

> The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for
>   the type JspFactory

This can also happen when your project requires a reference to a server runtime:

- Right click on your project in Eclipse's "Project Explorer"
- Choose "Build Path | Configure Build Path"
- Click on the "Libraries" tab
- Click "Add Library"
- Select "Server Runtime" and click "Next"
- Choose "Apache Tomcat 7", or whatever your server runtime version should be.

Note: This error can also happen for ANT builds, and for that case, you need to  reference a target runtime in your ANT build.xml file... The following references a local tomcat installation, and uses its "lib" folders when doing the compile:

```
<project name="tomcat-demo" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property name="tomcat-home" value="/path/to/your/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7" />

    <path id="project-classpath">
        <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${tomcat-home}/bin" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${tomcat-home}/common/lib" includes="*.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${tomcat-home}/server/lib" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>
   ...
</project>
```

Snagged from [this url](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-compile-my-project-using-ant.html?page=2):

Answer (score 1):

For Maven, I also had to add the jsp-api dependency as a provided jar like this:  (Some other dependency was pulling it in, I could never figure out which one, but this fixed it up)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```