# Struts2 project getting error - package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist

Tags: jsp, maven, struts2, netbeans-7

I've been setting up a Struts2 Project in Netbeans7 and actually got the project set up fine using Maven.

This isn't causing much of an issue as the project is working, but Im just getting this error in my jsp file as a red underline.

```
package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist
```

I googled a bit and ended up with a solution that had me adding in `jsp-api` into my dependencies. Once I added this in netbeans stopped showing me the error so i built and ran it again but now I get a server error.

```
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:389)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

After looking around here for a bit I came accross [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327118/howto-solve-jasper-exception-problem). I went through the three solutions here:

1. I am using Tomcat 7
2. My web.xml servlet version is 2.5 (i think)
3. I don't really understand this but thought it might be the case as I did put `jsp-api.jar` in my dependencies and `servlet-api.jar` is also there.

So I tried removing both `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from my dependencies to see if this would solve the problem. This just took me back to my original problem.

It's not a showstopper as the project is running fine and struts is working. But it is annoying and I would like to get rid of it as I can see it potentially causing problems later on. So if someone could think of something I haven't tried then that would be awesome!

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>New tradesman experience</display-name>
    <description>New tradesman experience</description>

    <!-- listeners -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- context params -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-tradesman.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:spring-tradesman.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- filter mappings -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change the scope of jsp-api and servlet-api in maven, set it **provided**.

Comment: huh, well that was easy. Thanks it worked. I take it doing that means its available for the IDE to see, but it doesnt try to use it when its built? (still getting to grips with maven)

Comment: that means that when deploying the app, "provided" are omitted(not deployed), because app server have them in the lib.

Comment: It means while building it will use the jars from maven repository. But while packaging the jar it won't copy those jars over to web-inf lib.