# The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I am working on a JSP project that uses Apache Tomcat 7.

When running the project on its loading *index.html* it's OK, but when trying to navigate to another page it's showing the error:

> The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Please provide me a solution to get rid of this.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Get rid of any servletcontainer-specific libraries such as `jsp-api.jar` in your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. This exception indicates that you've put servletcontainer-specific libraries of a container which supports only Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0 or older in there (the `getJspApplicationContext()` method was introduced in Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1). This is a major mistake. Those libraries don't belong in the webapp's classpath.

Perhaps you did this to overcome project compilation errors, which is indeed a pretty common beginner's mistake. This should have been solved differently, you should refer the target runtime in your project, not copy some libraries of an arbitrary servletcontainer make/version into your project. It would make your project incompatible with servletcontainers of a different make and/or version.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: Woow, you saved me, Thx :)

Answer (score 6):

if you have a maven project  try to add the following dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference a server runtime in your project.

In Eclipse:

- Choose "Project | Properties | Java Build Path | Libraries Tab"
- Click "Add Library | Server Runtime | Apache Tomcat 7"
- Click OK.
- Clean your project, and build it again ("Project | Clean", then "Project | Build All")

That should do it!

Note: See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2327159/26510) for more details on this problem

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error when working with an open source project using eclipse, the issue was with my tomcat version. I was using tomcat version 6. I had to setup a server using tomcat version 8 to resolve the issue.

this link was helpful [Unable to compile class for JSP](https://www.howopensource.com/2015/07/unable-to-compile-class-for-jsp-the-type-java-util-mapentry-cannot-be-resolved/)

Answer (score 0):

```
I am using Tomcat v8.0. 
This did not help:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
I checked all the runtime configurations and they all look fine. 
The jsp page does not load, but downloads a text file.
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35044942)