# How to get rid of servletcontainer-specific library jsp-api.jar?

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I am facing the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064269/the-method-getjspapplicationcontextservletcontext-is-undefined-for-the-type-js). I found a dependency to `jsp-api.jar`, which in fact comes from a dependency to Joda-Time:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I have tried to exclude it (see above), but the application won't compile. How do I make sure jsp-api is not shipped in my `.war`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of excluding this library, add to your dependencies explicitly with `provided` scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the appropriate version of the JSP API to the dependencies of your project, with the `provided` scope. It will be available at compile-time, but Maven will consider that it's provided by the runtime environment and thus don't ship it with the app.