# JSP compilation error in tomcat 8

Tags: jsp, gwt, smartgwt, tomcat8, smartgwt-pro

Previously I was using tomcat 7.0.30 and recently I moved to tomcat 8.0.21

After that, whenever I am trying to access my application, it gives JSP compilation error like below,

The return type is incompatible with JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

and below error also,

The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

I am also using GWT 2.7.0 and SmartGWT PRO 4.1

Can you please suggest the resolution for this ? I went through the suggested links but it didn't help. Updated struts to 2.3.20

Posting complete stacktrace below with -verbose:class VM argument,

```
    [Loaded org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/gwt-dev.jar]
[Loaded com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2 from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/xwork-core-2.3.20.jar]
[Loaded ognl.enhance.OrderedReturn from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar]
[Loaded ognl.ASTChain from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar]
[Loaded com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextState from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/xwork-core-2.3.20.jar]
[Loaded ognl.Evaluation from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.6.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$JspAttribute from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/jasper.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Vector$ListItr from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.RecoveryScanner from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CharConstant from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.ByteConstant from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar]
[Loaded org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SynchronizedStatement from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.jasper.compiler.JavacErrorDetail from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/jasper.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/UDMUI/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.20.jar]
Apr 08, 2015 3:51:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/UDMUI] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\work\Catalina\localhost\UDMUI\org\apache\jsp\login\login_jsp.java]
The return type is incompatible with JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

An error occurred at line: [56] in the generated java file: [E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\work\Catalina\localhost\UDMUI\org\apache\jsp\login\login_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\work\Catalina\localhost\UDMUI\org\apache\jsp\login\login_jsp.java]
The return type is incompatible with JspSourceDependent.getDependants()

An error occurred at line: [56] in the generated java file: [E:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\work\Catalina\localhost\UDMUI\org\apache\jsp\login\login_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:580)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[Loaded org.apache.catalina.util.RequestUtil from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/catalina.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Scanner from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$All from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$6 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.LRUCache from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Scanner$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.util.http.ValuesEnumerator from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.AcceptLanguage from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.locale.LanguageTag from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.locale.ParseStatus from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.locale.StringTokenIterator from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.locale.InternalLocaleBuilder from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.util.locale.InternalLocaleBuilder$CaseInsensitiveChar from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.catalina.util.ConcurrentDateFormat from file:/E:/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/lib/catalina.jar]
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete StackTrace?

Comment: Posted the complete stacktrace. Thanks

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064269/the-method-getjspapplicationcontextservletcontext-is-undefined-for-the-type-js

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gwt-dev.jar file if you are including it.

I had this problem recently. It tends to happen when there's is a conflicting jar that contains a definition of JspFactory as described here-

[The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064269/the-method-getjspapplicationcontextservletcontext-is-undefined-for-the-type-js)

With GWT, check if you are including the gwt-dev.jar file. It also contains a definition for the JSPFactory. That's what was causing the issue when I had it. Remove it. You probably don't need it at run time and don't need to include the jar.