# Unable to compile class for JSP with Spring MVC

Tags: spring

I am new in Spring MVC, I am trying to create a simple Hello World Program but when I run the program it shows the following error :

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [34] in the generated java file: [D:\workspace\SpringTest1.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\SpringMVC3Test1\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am using Tomcat 7, JDK 7, Eclipse(LUNA). I have no idea about the problem and how to create simple application in Spring MVC. Please solve this problem, and if possible tell me step by step procedure of creating simple Spring MVC Hello World Program. I am fadeup of searching this in google

Answer (score 0):

See [The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064269/the-method-getjspapplicationcontextservletcontext-is-undefined-for-the-type-js)

If you don't want to bother with configuration problems take a look at the Spring Guides and use Spring Boot:
https://spring.io/guides/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/